# Scala, Spark, Geotrellis Rdd CRS reprojection

Tags: scala, apache-spark, geotrellis

I load a set of point from a CSV file to a RDD:

```
case class yieldrow(Elevation:Double,DryYield:Double)

val points :RDD[PointFeature[yieldrow]] = lines.map { line =>
  val fields = line.split(",")
  val point = Point(fields(1).toDouble,fields(0).toDouble)
  Feature(point, yieldrow(fields(4).toDouble,fields(20)))
}
```

Then get:

```
points: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[geotrellis.vector.PointFeature[yieldrow]]
```

Now need to reproject from EPSG:4326 to  EPSG:3270

So I create the CRS from and to:

```
val crsFrom : geotrellis.proj4.CRS =  geotrellis.proj4.CRS.fromName("EPSG:4326")
val crsTo : geotrellis.proj4.CRS =  geotrellis.proj4.CRS.fromEpsgCode(32720)
```

But I can not create the transform and also i don not know:

Hot to apply a transform to a single point:

```
val pt = Point( -64.9772376007928, -33.6408083223936)
```

How to use the mapGeom method of Feature to make a CRS transformation ?

```
points.map(_.mapGeom(?????))
points.map(feature => feature.mapGeom(????))
```

How to use ReprojectPointFeature(pointfeature) ?

The documentation not have basic code samples.

Any help will be appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start from the last question:

Indeed to perform a reproject on a `PointFeature` you can use `ReprojectPointFeature` implict case class. To use it just be sure that you have `import geotrellis.vector._` in `reproject` function call scope.

```
import geotrellis.vector._
points.map(_.reproject(crsFrom, crsTo))
```

The same import works for a `Point` too:

```
import geotrellis.vector._
pt.reproject(crsFrom, crsTo)
points.map(_.mapGeom(_.reproject(crsFrom, crsTo)))
```

Comment: Thanks,
I read the API and the Geometry don not have the reproject method: 
http://geotrellis.github.io/scaladocs/latest/#geotrellis.vector.Geometry

But there is a Implicits in geotrellis.vector.reproject.Implicits
http://geotrellis.github.io/scaladocs/latest/#geotrellis.vector.reproject.Implicits$ReprojectGeometry

So now understand that it work using the implicits way.

Comment: trying ftRdd.map(_.mapGeom(_.reproject(crsFrom, crsTo))), give me org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable: Task not serializable